# Why does the mixture's temperature change while phase transition?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, boiling-point, melting-point

Consider a mixture made up of alcohol and water at room temperature. If I freeze this mixture, why does it change its temperature during the phase change?

I don't understand the difference between the case when you have a pure substance (only water or only alcohol) and that one. How could it be different (I mean, in molecular thinking...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concentration of water decreases as the mixture cools, so one is left with fairly pure ice, freezing at ~273 K, and pure(r) ethanol, freezing ~159 K (well, the eutectic mixture, about 93% ethanol). Since the ratio of the components are changing as it freezes, there is no distinct freezing point (unless you *start* with the eutectic mixture). See the [phase diagram for ethanol-water mixture](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Phase_diagram_ethanol_water_s_l_en.svg). Instead, the slush mix has a range of *solidus* and *liquidus* temperature. BTW, this is a method to make *apple jack* or brandy by freezing out water from cider or wine.

The same is noticed with solder, where it crystallizes gradually and dully, except for the sudden freezing of a eutectic mix (~63% Sn, ~37% Pb), making a shiny joint.